# jsPdf html to pdf - text overflow cutting some of the last text (react)

Tags: reactjs, jspdf

I am trying to use jsPdf to generate a pdf from an html string.
I am able to generate pdf using the code below.

```
 const generatePDF = () => {
    const pdf = new jsPDF({
      orientation: "p",
      unit: "pt",
      format: "a4",
    });
    const width = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth(); 
    pdf
      .html(htmlContent, {
        width: width,
        windowWidth: 794,
        margin: [58, 80, 52, 80],
        html2canvas: { scale: 0.57 },
      })
      .then(() => { 
        pdf.save('test.pdf');
      });
  };
```

However, i think the page break is now working as expected. in some pages, text is split between pages like this
`[![enter code here][1]][1]`
[image]

Anyone has a clue how to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

You should probably use [html2pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf.js/v/0.9.0) instead of jspdf. It uses jspdf but is easier to use. Add a page break and it should be ok.